# Unable to open firefox using selenium-python-geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Newbee here! Help out guys!

**Environment:** Windows 10.1 (64Bit) + Selenium + Python + geckodriver.exe (latest version - v0.13.0 - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

**Issue:**

- Unable to open the firefox browser using the code mentioned below

**Code Used:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\geckodriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Firefox(path)
browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

**Note:**

- Able to open Chrome & IE Edge using chromewebdriver & Microsoftwebdriver by changing the location path accordingly
- Setted the windows environment path environment too. Check below:

  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver
  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32
  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts

**Questions:**

1. What is the issue? Gave correct location path. Still unable to open
2. Is path set in environment variables above is correct? I tried changing it many times and no use. Could someone please share your working environment variable path?

Kindly reply! Thanks for your time!

Comment: Share your error traceback

Answer (score 1):

try to use executable_path ,
this param use to specify the path to run geckodriver

```
base_path = "./"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=os.path.join(base_path, "geckodriver"), **config)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following and let me know whether it solved your issue or not

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium import webdriver

path = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\geckodriver.exe'
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\Path\to\firefox.exe') # Set your own path
browser = webdriver.Firefox(path, firefox_binary=binary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following value to PATH :

1. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox (i.e., till geckodriver.exe)`

When looking for files/exes in that PATH, it won't look inside the sub-folders of that path.

**Or**

Keep the geckodriver.exe in one of the following paths, which are already added to `PATH`:

```
 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts
 2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32
 3. C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver
```

Note: System Restart may be necessary.